# Creating a while loop in java that prompts the customer to order more food if 1 and exit if two, understanding while loop

Tags: java

I am creating a menu that adds up the total amount of items ordered from a user. I wrote a `while` loop that gets the first total of the item ordered but I would like the code to prompt the user again and add different items to the running total. Basically I want it to run back through the loop again if they want more food. I'm thinking I am a little confused about `break` and `continue`. Here is the code I have so far.

```java
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner moreFood = new Scanner (System.in);
        // Declares the variable menuItem and stores the keyboard input in that variable
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 to order food from our menu or 0 to exit");
        int order = moreFood.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the menu number of the food you would like to order or 0 to stop ordering");
        int menuItem = input.nextInt();
        if (order==1) {
            while (order == 1) { 
                if (menuItem == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(total);
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen small pizza! A perfect size pizza for just one! " + "$" + smallPizza);
                    total += smallPizza;
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen medium pizza! A pizza big enough to share...or not " + "$" + mediumPizza);
                    total += mediumPizza;
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen large pizza. A pizza big enough for the whole family! " + "$" + largePizza);
                    total += largePizza;
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println ("You've chosen Veggie Burger! A black bean burger with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press. " + "$" + veggieBurger);
                    total += veggieBurger;
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 5)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen Grilled Chicken Sandwich! Grilled Chicken topped with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + grilledChickenSandwich);
                    total += grilledChickenSandwich;
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 6)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen a Hamburger! Classic 100% beef patty with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + hamburgerSandwich);
                    total += hamburgerSandwich;
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 7)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen Mac and Cheese! Not your momma's mac! Spicy 3 Cheese Mac made with Red Pepper Flakes. Beware the spice! " + "$" + macAndCheese);
                    total += macAndCheese;
                    break;
                }
                else if(menuItem == 8)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen Hand Cut Fries! Crisp, golden fries deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + handCutFries);
                    total += handCutFries;
                    break;
                }
                else if (menuItem == 9)
                {
                    System.out.println("You've chosen Onion Rings! Crisp, golden rings of onion deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + onionRings);
                    total += onionRings;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Choice! Try Again!");
                }
                System.out.println("Please enter a 1 to order more food or 0 to proceed to checkout");
            }
        }
    } // end of main
}// end of class
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `do while` loop ?

Comment: ```if (order==1) {
    while (order == 1) {``` is redundant. you don't need the if

Comment: also break stops the loop completely so probably isn't what you want

Comment: You may also want to look at using Java's switch functionality. It provides a simpler way of creating "if" and "else if" conditions that are paired together. Here is a link: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp

Comment: Thank you all! I think I will simplify it with a switch statement instead if else is a little drawn out

Answer (score 2):

1. The `if` statement before the while loop is redundant.
2. You don't need two scanners, just reuse the one.
3. It's probably a better idea to declare the scanner inside main then pass it to the function.
4. `break` will stop the loop completely and `continue` will skip that iteration.

The code below should work

```
    public static void order(Scanner scanner) {
        // Declares the variable menuItem and stores the keyboard input in that variable
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 to order food from our menu or 0 to exit");
        System.out.println("Please enter the menu number of the food you would like to order or 0 to stop ordering");
        double total = 0.0;
        while (true) {
            int menuItem = scanner.nextInt();
            if (menuItem == 0){
                System.out.println(total);
                break;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 1){
                System.out.println("You've chosen small pizza! A perfect size pizza for just one! " + "$" + "smallPizza");
                total += 10.0d;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 2){
                System.out.println("You've chosen medium pizza! A pizza big enough to share...or not " + "$" + "mediumPizza");
                total += 12.0d;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 3){
                System.out.println("You've chosen large pizza. A pizza big enough for the whole family! " + "$" + "largePizza");
                total += 14.0d;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 4){
                System.out.println ("You've chosen Veggie Burger! A black bean burger with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press. " + "$" + "veggieBurger");
                total += 16.3d;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 5){
                System.out.println("You've chosen Grilled Chicken Sandwich! Grilled Chicken topped with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce, PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + "grilledChickenSandwich");
                total += 13.5d;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 6){
                System.out.println("You've chosen a Hamburger! Classic 100% beef patty with Tomato, Mayo, Lettuce and PepperJack Cheese. All grilled on a panini press " + "$" + "hamburgerSandwich");
                total += 14.0d;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 7){
                System.out.println("You've chosen Mac and Cheese! Not your momma's mac! Spicy 3 Cheese Mac made with Red Pepper Flakes. Beware the spice! " + "$" + "macAndCheese");
                total += 11.0d;
            }
            else if(menuItem == 8){
                System.out.println("You've chosen Hand Cut Fries! Crisp, golden fries deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + "handCutFries");
                total += 12.0d;
            }
            else if (menuItem == 9){
                System.out.println("You've chosen Onion Rings! Crisp, golden rings of onion deep fried in peanut oil " + "$" + "onionRings");
                total += 2.0d;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Choice! Try Again!");
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter a 1 to order more food or 0 to proceed to checkout");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        order(userInput);
    }
```